odoo 17.0 'always_reload' don't exists, what's the equivalent in this verison?
I have an issue with the delivery address. I want to show the partner address on the stock.picking.batch.form. Right now, the content (a part of) of the view is like this:
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
                    <field
                        name="partner_id"
                        readonly="1"
                        context="{'show_address': 1}"
                        options="{'always_reload': True}"
                    />
                    <field name="date" />
    </xpath>

I tested the same view on v14.0, and is working properly, but in the v17 don't work...anybody have any idea?

notice that i have changed the quotes to submite the code, stackoverflow don't allowed me to post it

What do you mean by "don't work"? Can you describe that in more detail: what are your expectations, what is actually happening? IIRC that option is not needed anymore, but i'm not entirely sure.

Oh and i edited the quotes again and added syntax highlighting.

The behavior I expect by setting the show_address and always_reload is to force the partner address to appear, I have tested it in version 14.0 and it works correctly, but I don't know why but in 17.0 it doesn't.
